Как установить Windows 10 на новый ноутбук ASUS VivaBook X1504ZA
Купил новый ноутбук ASUS VivaBook X1504ZA, а там нет винды. Пробовал создать установочную флешку по инструкции на официальном сайте asus.
В итоге ставлю флешку в ноутбук и после рестарта жму кнопку ESC, чтобы запустить установку. Открывается такой экран http://surl.li/syrqjg. Как понял, либо не читает флешку, либо формат установочного файла не тот.
Пробовал зайти в BIOS с помощью кнопки F2 во время включения ноутбука, открывается такой экран http://surl.li/tkvfls, то есть ничего нового не происходит.
Дальше вроде додумался, что этот функционал http://surl.li/tkvfls играет роль BIOS и в разделе "Дополнительные настройки / Дополнительно" нашел раздел "Обновление прошивки ASUS" http://surl.li/gjfxwt Как видно из скрина флешку ноут все-таки читает, но воспринимает установочный файл как отдельные папки. Именно поэтому решил, что вопрос просто в формате установочного файла.
В сети нашел рекомендацию отформатировать файл в UEFI GPT формат. То есть сделал все опять же по инструкции с официального сайта asus, только на этом шаге https://kmpic.asus.com/images/2020/09/17/874c0cfc-5b0d-42ec-bf06-84aee3f71e2b.png вместо USB flash drive выбрал ISO файл. Далее с помощью rufus отформатировал образ как в скрине http://surl.li/jtuxjm.
В итоге опять ноутбук отдельные папки в флешке, не воспринимает установочный файл.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком шаге и что делаю не то?
Спасибо!

В BIOS отображаются подключенные девайсы(в том числе в списке должна быть флешка, если он её видит) и должна быть опция выставления приоритета загрузки(у вас на скрине опций F2 она внизу слева). Установочная флешка ставится на первая место, чтобы с неё начиналась загрузка. Дальше надо смотреть по ошибкам и поведению, если они будут. Ну еще файловую систему в rufus можно выставить как NTFS вместо FAT32.

Судя по уровню знаний, Вам всё-таки лучше нанять за смешные деньги самого хоть как-то квалифицированного специалиста или студента ИТ. Это я Вам советую, как человек, который устанавливает Windows 30 лет, начиная с Windows 3.11. Всё, что Вами написано в вопросе - не то и не о том. Вы просто потеряете время, а результаты будут настолько жалкими, что в результате в сети появится очередной рассказчик о том, какая Windows 11 плохая, живущий в режиме от аварии до аварии.

@AlexKrass А флешка должна появится в разделе "Внешний порт USB" на экране http://surl.li/tkvfls, я правильно понимаю? Или в приоритете загрузки должна появится 2 строка? У меня ни там, ни там не видна  флешка. Это проблема связана с форматом? То есть поможет ли, если я вместо FAT32 выставлю NTFS ? И на каком варианте установочного файла остановиться? USB flash drive или ISO файл?

В приоритете загрузки должен быть выбор из Windows Boot Manager и флеш накопителя. Я пока не встречал особо, чтобы была проблема с NTFS и хотя бы определять он её должен, хотя всё может быть. Попробуйте еще по этой инструкции выполнить настройки BIOS (хотя он там визуально чуть отличается): https://www.asus.com/ru/support/faq/1013017/ Заодно по скриншотам посмотрите, что имеется ввиду в плане выбора приоритета загрузки.

В установщике Windows выбор делается USB flash drive для флешек, второй нужен для записи образа на оптический диск. В rufus выбирается ISO образ системы Windows. Загрузочную флешку можно получить этими двумя способами независимо друг от друга.

@AlexKrass по вашему совету поменял формат на NTFS и теперь флешка отображается http://surl.li/xzslwy. Нашел раздел выставления приоритета загрузки http://surl.li/abaeza, но в параметрах пусто. Поскольку есть возможность создать параметр, решил попробовать. http://surl.li/oymunp Открывается такое меню http://surl.li/ocudfm Тут выбрал "Boot" и далее "bootx64efi" http://surl.li/oxvwzf Параметр сохранился http://surl.li/krbkgo. Перезагрузил ноут в надежде, что поможет, но установка не загружается. Подскажите, где ошибся? Я так понимаю ошибка в выборе пути параметра загрузки?

Параметры загрузки это вроде не то, я еще тут видео нашел, там при загрузке ноутбука нажимают ESC для вызова меню загрузки и там в списке должна быть флешка: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH7yEVNfvRI Вам нужно найти меню, где будет выбор, откуда начинается загрузка - просто должна быть указана флешка и выбрать её, без указания чего-то дополнительного.
